# Unable to install Dropbox on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, dropbox

I am trying to install Dropbox on ubuntu 12.04, but in terminal setup stops after downloading 100%.

Comment: What command do you use to install dropbox via terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From **.deb** file

Download dropbox .Deb from  :- [Here!](https://www.dropbox.com/install?os=lnx)

after downloading type :-

```
sudo dpkg -i * .deb
```

install dropbox from **command line** :-

for **32** Bit :-

```
cd ~ && wget -O - "https://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86" | tar xzf
```

for **64** Bit :-

```
cd ~ && wget -O - "https://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86_64" | tar xzf -
```

after this type :-

```
~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
```

[source](https://www.dropbox.com/install?os=lnx)